# How to identify dict keys with spaces without removing whitespaces

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose d is a dict

```
d={' a ':1,'b ':2}
```

if we give like this

```
d.has_key(' a ')
True
```

but this is false

```
d.has_key('a')
False
```

so i tried like this

```
d.has_key('\sa\s')
False
```

so how to find dict keys having spaces without stripping their whitespaces

thanks in advance

Comment: Not. You will have to strip the key at some point. Is `has_key` (which btw. is deprecated, prefer `in`) your main operation?

Comment: @larsmans if we use in it will not match entire key, it will match substring also..

Comment: @user1182090 - he pointed out, that `'a' in d` should be used instead of `d.has_key('a')`, both of them matching whole keys only.

Comment: @larsmans even 'in' matches whole key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to remove them:

```
d = {' a ':1,'b ':2}
key = 'a'
print any(key == k.strip() for k in d.iterkeys())
```

prints `True`

To get the value, you can use this method:

```
def get_stripped(d, key):
    return next((v for k,v in d.iteritems() if key == k.strip()), None)

print get_stripped(d, 'a') # prints 1
print get_stripped(d, 'c') # prints None
```

This will return just one arbitrary value if `d = {' a ': 1, '   a': 2}` and `key = 'a'`.

Comment: it prints true but how to access value , if i give d[key] it will give key error....

Comment: Breaks the benefit of fast lookups that `dict`s usually provide.

Comment: @martineau - of course it would be better to create a new dict with correctly stripped keys.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it quite often, you can subclass `dict`:

```
class D(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(D, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._skeys = dict((k.strip(), v) for k, v in self.iteritems())

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        super(D, self).__setitem__(key, val)
        self._skeys[key.strip()] = key

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except KeyError:
            return self[self._skeys[key]]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return (dict.__contains__(self, key) or key in self._skeys)
```

usage:

```
d = D({'a':1, 'b':2})
d['  c  '] = 3
print 'c' in d # True
print d['c'] # 3
```

This class works fine, if `key_n.strip() != key_m.strip()` is True for any `n != m`

Comment: Ought to provide an overload for `has_key()` too, even if it's deprecated, otherwise it won't be consistent with  results from `__contains__()`.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the subclass would also need custom versions of all methods that could modify it contents, like `clear()`, `__delitem__()`, `setdefault()`, etc -- potentially a lot more code than you've shown. Doable, but a fair amount of work...

Comment: @martineau, it's not complete implementation, but only sketch to show the conception :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this *generator expression*: `'a' in (item.strip() for item in d.keys())`

```
>>> d={' a ':1, 'b ':2}
>>> 'a' in (item.strip() for item in d.keys())
True
>>> 'b' in (item.strip() for item in d.keys())
True
>>> 'c' in (item.strip() for item in d.keys())
False
>>> d
>>> {' a ': 1, 'b ': 2}
```

**edit**

For accessing the value, you can:

```
>>> for key, value in d.iteritems():
if key.strip()=='a':
    print value
1
```

Or, one-liner version:

```
>>> [value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key.strip() == 'a'][0]
1
>>> [value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key.strip() == 'b'][0]
2
```

Basically, `[value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key.strip() == 'b']` will return a list of values and `[0]` for selecting the first one. If you have several similar keys, like:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, ' a':2, ' a ':3}
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> values = [value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key.strip() == 'a']
>>> len(values)
3
>>> values[0]
1
>>> values[1]
2
>>> values[2]
3
```

Comment: @ cblab this is fine but how to access d['a'] if d has ' a '.. thats what my question

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a dictionary of stripped values if you need to test many.

```
>>> d={' a ':1,'b ':2}
>>> t = dict( (pair[0].strip(), pair) for pair in d.iteritems())
>>> print t.has_key('a')
True
>>> print t['a']
(' a ', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {' a':'b',' c ':'c','b ':'b'}
key = ' a'
[d[l] for l in  d.iterkeys() if l.strip() == key.strip()]
['b']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>d = {' a ':1, 'b ':2}
>>>dd = dict((l.strip(), v) for l, v in d.iteritems())
>>>dd
{'a':1, 'b':2}
>>>'a' in dd
True
>>>d['a']
1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept shown in @astynax's answer -- deriving a dictionary subclass -- was on the right track however it's incomplete...probably because providing a complete dictionary subclass can be a lot of work since there are quite a few interrelated methods that would need to be overridden.

A shortcut to avoid that is to derive a subclass from the `UserDict.DictMixin` class instead of `dict`. The advantage is that it would reduce the number of methods that have to be written to a minimum of four. More efficiency can be obtained by also implementing several additional ones as an optimization.

Here's a complete working example that does this, resulting in something which behave almost exactly like a dictionary object except for the desired ignoring of any white-space around the keys. Except possibly when deleting keys, performance should be nearly as good as that of a standard dictionary, although it does use more memory.

```
import UserDict

class WhiteOut(UserDict.DictMixin):
    """ Mapping object with white space insensitive keys """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._dict = dict(*args, **kwargs)
        self._skeys = dict((k.strip(), v) for k, v in self._dict.iteritems())

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self._dict.__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return self._skeys.__getitem__(key.strip())

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self._dict.__setitem__(key, val)
        self._skeys.__setitem__(key.strip(), val)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        try:
            self._dict.__delitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            stripped_key = key.strip()
            try:
                self._skeys.__delitem__(stripped_key)
            except KeyError:
                raise
            else:  # delete item corresponding to stripped_key in _dict
                for akey in self._dict:
                    if akey.strip() == stripped_key:
                        self._dict.__delitem__(akey)
                        return

    def keys(self):
        return self._dict.keys()

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return self._skeys.__contains__(key.strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wo = WhiteOut({'a':1, ' b':2})
    wo['  c  '] = 3
    print 'c' in wo # True
    print wo['c'] # 3
    print 'has_key:'
    print wo.has_key('  c  ')
    print wo.has_key('c')
    print wo['c '] # 3
    print 'wo.keys():', wo.keys()
    wokeys = [k for k in wo]
    print 'wo keys via iteration:', wokeys
    wo.pop("b")
    print 'wo.keys() after pop("b"):', wo.keys()
    try:
        wo.pop('not there')
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        print "wo.pop('not there') didn't raise an exception as it should have"
```